# How to open .ovr files in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

raster data i have downloaded from CGIAR, Which contains .ovr files. It is not opening in Arcgis. How to open .ovr files and how to process them?

Answer (score 9):

The [.ovr file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000026000000) contains the image pyramids, which allows you to quickly and efficiently view images at a variety of scales.  You can read more about raster pyramids [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000019000000).  These files are not intended to be opened or edited directly.  They are attached to image files such as .tif format images.  A more common workflow would be to delete and/or create a .ovr file. In ArcGIS, you can build pyramids using the [Build Pyramids (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m1000000) or [Build Pyramids And Statistics (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m9000000) tools.  You can read more on deleting pyramids [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000255000000).

Answer (score 0):

I am new-bee in ArcGIS. Currently I have a task to open a bundled files like:

- some_map.tfw            1 kb
- some_map.tif            133,666 kb
- some_map.tif.aux.xml    2 kb
- some_map.tif.ovr        45,645 kb

here, the `tfw` file seems to be a world file,
and `aux.xml` is an auxiliary file, help ArcGIS to understand the total files.
`tif` is the base image file, and the `ovr` is the "image pyramids" of the raster.

So, I think you just need to open the `aux` file, or the `tif` file, you will see the both  `tif` and the `tif.ovr` files.

(in short: `tif.ovr` file will be auto-shown when you open the related `tif` file)

This is my result (changed color-bet from the "layer" tab, opened in ArcMap)

[image]